# How to disable Google compute engine from resetting SFTP folder permissions when using SSH-Key

Tags: ssh, permissions, metadata, google-compute-engine, sftp

Currently running a Google compute engine instance and using SFTP on the server.

Followed details to lock a user to the SFTP path using steps listed here: https://bensmann.no/restrict-sftp-users-to-home-folder/

**To lock the user to a directory, the home directory of that user needs to be owned by root.** Initially, the setup worked correctly but found that **Google compute engine sporadically "auto-resets" the permissions back to the user.**

I am using an SSH key that is set in the Google Cloud Console and that key is associated with the username. My guess is that Google Compute Engine is using this "meta-data" and reconfiguring the folder permissions to match that of the user associated with the SSH key.

**Is there any way to disable this "auto-reset"?** Or, rather, is there a better method to hosting SFTP and locking a single user to a SFTP path without having to change the home folder ownership to root?

Answer (score 0):

Set your sshd rule to apply to the [google-sudoers](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py#L45) group.

The tool that manages user accounts is [accounts daemon](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py). You can turn it off temporarily but it's not recommended. The tool syncs the instance metadata's SSH keys with the linux accounts on the VM. If you do this any account changes won't be picked up, SSH from Cloud Console will probably stop working.

```
sudo systemctl stop google-accounts-daemon.service
```

That said it may be what you want if you ultimately want to block SSH access to the VM.